# Handle procedure that can take a null parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have the following hierarchical table:

```
+------+------+----------+
| pkID | fkID | fkIDType |
+------+------+----------+
|    1 | NULL |        1 |
|    2 | NULL |        1 |
|    3 | NULL |        1 |
|    4 | 1    |        1 |
|    5 | 1    |        1 |
|    6 | NULL |        2 |
|    7 | 6    |        2 |
|    8 | 7    |        2 |
+------+------+----------+
```

I have a procedure that updates the table. The procedure takes two argument, a `fkIDType` and a `fkID`. `fkIDType` cannot be null. `fkID` can be `NULL`. I use both parameters to filter my table and then the procedures updates the table. If `fkID` is `NULL`, I want to update all the rows that are part of that `fkIDType`. So I have the following

```
IF @fkID IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        dbo.table
    SET
        -- We set some info
    WHERE   
            fkIDType = @fkIDType
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        dbo.table
    SET
        -- We set some info
    WHERE   
            fkIDType = @fkIDType
        AND fkID = @fkID
END
```

Is there a way to simplify the query without hurting performance ? I tried filtering like `ISNULL(fkID, -999) = ISNULL(@fkID, -999)`, but then I will only get the null values instead of everything

Comment: . These two queries are as simple as possible. Each of them will use a *different* execution plan, different indexes

Comment: I asked the question because I do multiple queries in that table and everytime, I must handle those two cases... If I refactor, then I have twice the amount of code to handle (change in columns, where clause, etc). I'm surprised there is no native way to handle that case

Comment: The two queries are *not* the same at all. A query is just text that gets compiled to an execution plan, which takes into account existing indexes and data statistics to decide which indexes to use, which join, filter strategies, what to parallelise etc.

Comment: The first query would only use a single index. The second would use two. If you tried to combine them the way granadaCoder proposes you could end up using only one index in the second case. Since the second query uses a very specific ID, you could end up scanning (and locking) 100 or 1000 rows when you could just touch a single row.  The problem with `catch-all` queries is well known

Comment: One way to avoid this problem with catch-all queries is to add `WITH RECOMPILE` in your stored procedure. Instead of caching the execution plan, the server will parse the stored procedure each time it's called. This will negate any performance benefit you'd get from a stored procedure

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I'll check into that. Should I close/delete the question or maybe you want to answer it for other users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  UPDATE
        dbo.table
  SET /* blah blah */
  FROM
       dbo.table origTable
  WHERE   
      fkIDType = @fkIDType
      AND

(((
((  origTable.fkID IS NULL AND @fkID IS NULL))
OR
      fkID =
          CASE
             WHEN @fkID IS NULL then origTable.fkID /* the trick is.. when your parameter IS NULL, match on the same/existing column, which will always match */
             ELSE @fkID
          END
)))
```

**These types of "tricks" can hurt performance on large tables.  So do not use them blindly.**

FULL Generic Example:

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Toy]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)

BEGIN

DROP TABLE [dbo].[Toy]

END

GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Toy] (

[ToyUUID] [uniqueidentifier] primary key not null default NEWSEQUENTIALID() ,

ToyName varchar(64) not null,
[MacroStatusKey] smallint NOT NULL ,
[CreateDateUtc] [datetimeoffset] NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
[UpdateDateUtc] [datetimeoffset] NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

CONSTRAINT Toy_RootName_UNIQUE UNIQUE (ToyName)

)

GO




INSERT INTO dbo.Toy ( ToyUUID , ToyName , [MacroStatusKey] ) 
SELECT '88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000011', 'TeddyBear' ,   1
UNION ALL SELECT '88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000021', 'Doll' ,  1
UNION ALL SELECT '88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000071', 'Ball' ,  1
UNION ALL SELECT '88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000081', 'CardboardBox' ,  1


SELECT * from dbo.Toy


Declare @MyToyUUID uniqueidentifier

SELECT @MyToyUUID = '88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000011'

UPDATE
    dbo.Toy
SET MacroStatusKey = 44
FROM
    dbo.Toy origTable
WHERE   
    ToyUUID =
        CASE
            WHEN @MyToyUUID IS NULL then origTable.ToyUUID 
            ELSE @MyToyUUID
        END





SELECT * from dbo.Toy



SELECT @MyToyUUID = NULL

UPDATE
    dbo.Toy
SET MacroStatusKey = 55
FROM
    dbo.Toy origTable
WHERE   
    ToyUUID =
        CASE
            WHEN @MyToyUUID IS NULL then origTable.ToyUUID 
            ELSE @MyToyUUID
        END


SELECT * from dbo.Toy





-----------------




UPDATE
    dbo.Toy
SET MacroStatusKey = NULL
FROM
    dbo.Toy origTable
WHERE
    ToyName = 'TeddyBear'


SELECT ToyUUID, ToyName, MacroStatusKey from dbo.Toy


Declare @MyMacroStatus int
SELECT @MyMacroStatus = NULL

UPDATE
    dbo.Toy
SET MacroStatusKey = 77
FROM
    dbo.Toy origTable
WHERE   
    origTable.MacroStatusKey IS NULL
    OR
    MacroStatusKey =
        CASE
            WHEN @MyMacroStatus IS NULL then origTable.MacroStatusKey 
            ELSE @MyMacroStatus
        END


    SELECT 'With IS NULL OR check', ToyUUID, ToyName, MacroStatusKey from dbo.Toy





UPDATE
    dbo.Toy
SET MacroStatusKey = NULL
FROM
    dbo.Toy origTable
    
UPDATE
    dbo.Toy
SET MacroStatusKey = 111
FROM
    dbo.Toy origTable
WHERE
    ToyName = 'TeddyBear'


SELECT ToyUUID, ToyName, MacroStatusKey from dbo.Toy

SELECT @MyMacroStatus = 111

UPDATE
    dbo.Toy
SET MacroStatusKey = 112
FROM
    dbo.Toy origTable
WHERE   
    (( origTable.MacroStatusKey IS NULL AND @MyMacroStatus IS NULL))
    OR
    MacroStatusKey =
        CASE
            WHEN @MyMacroStatus IS NULL then origTable.MacroStatusKey 
            ELSE @MyMacroStatus
        END


SELECT ToyUUID, ToyName, MacroStatusKey from dbo.Toy
```

Results:

(below, seed data)

```
ToyUUID ToyName MacroStatusKey
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000011    TeddyBear   1
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000021    Doll    1
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000071    Ball    1
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000081    CardboardBox    1
```

(below, update where @MyToyUUID = '88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000011')

```
ToyUUID ToyName MacroStatusKey
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000011    TeddyBear   44
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000021    Doll    1
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000071    Ball    1
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000081    CardboardBox    1
```

(below, update where @MyToyUUID is null)

```
ToyUUID ToyName MacroStatusKey
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000011    TeddyBear   55
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000021    Doll    55
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000071    Ball    55
88888888-8888-8888-8888-000000000081    CardboardBox    55
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my query, I had `fkID IS NULL` in the first block, but it shouldn't be there, because if `@fkID` is `NULL`, I would like to display everything associated with the `fkIDType`.

Comment: I tried your query, but it removes values where `fkID` is `NULL`, since `NULL = NULL` is false

Comment: But then, if the `@fkID` is not null, it will return the null values, which I do not want, since a `@fkID` was specified

Comment: I updated the answer.  You basically need to cover all "cases" with the AND OR and CASE for your specific needs.

Comment: Agreed it "will" hurt performance.   (and upvoted your comment)  But it depends on the number of rows and indexes on the table.   Super (or I guess "more") flexible can put the hurt on high performance. #pickPoison  More code to maintain ... vs "tricks" for the sql.

Comment: Don't propose such code then. This code will generate inefficient execution plans for half the cases. There are ways to avoid that - one way is to use `WITH RECOMPILE` and force a recompilation every time the stored procedure is executed. Using a catch-all parameter doesn't result in cleaner code either

Comment: if your table has 1000 rows, these answers are "ok".  If you have millions of rows...then .. no, this isn't a great answer.  I'll put a footnote in the answer, but i don't agree with "never show these answers" approach.

Comment: No they aren't. Even for a few thousand, this will result in bad performance - a table scan even when an index is available, or seeking an index that isn't really needed. Besides, it's easy to fix it by just adding a `WITH RECOMPILE`

Comment: My table has millions of rows, and performance cannot be hindered. I will read of `WITH RECOMPILE`, since I'm unsure what that command does

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15